# Infinite dimensional spaces span

Tags: vector-spaces

I have a problem that I would like to check if I did right.

Let **E** be the set of vectors $(e_1,e_2,...)$ in $R^\infty$, and let $w = (1,1,1,...)$. Describe the span of the set $(w,e_1,e_2,...)$.

Well, $span(E \cup w)=span(w,e_1,e_2,...)=\{$finite combinations of elements of $E \cup w\}$ = Sequences with finitely many terms different from $c_0 + c_n,$ where $c_i \in F:$

So, the answer is $\{(a) \in R^\infty|a_n=c_0$ for all but finitely many $n\}$

Does this look right? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Looks right. A commonly used term is "eventually constant" sequences.